# Jquery AutoComplete Extender with JSON Array String

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

```js
<script>

        $(function () {
            var myArray = '[{"OriginId":2609,"OriginName":"14th Mile Stone"},{"OriginId":2007,"OriginName":"Aachara"},{"OriginId":2220,"OriginName":"Aarni"},{"OriginId":2216,"OriginName":"Aasind"},{"OriginId":637,"OriginName":"Aathankarai"},{"OriginId":1292,"OriginName":"Aatthur"},{"OriginId":1144,"OriginName":"Aavanam"},{"OriginId":2909,"OriginName":"Abad (Airport)"},{"OriginId":379,"OriginName":"Abiramam"},{"OriginId":4556,"OriginName":"ABLOLI"},{"OriginId":4554,"OriginName":"ABLOLI KALE HOUSE"},{"OriginId":2346,"OriginName":"Abohar"},{"OriginId":2500,"OriginName":"Abu Road"},{"OriginId":4395,"OriginName":"ACHALPUR"},{"OriginId":1594,"OriginName":"Achanta"},{"OriginId":2769,"OriginName":"Adda Road"}]';

            var jsonString = JSON.parse(myArray);
            $('#busPoint').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.getJSON(jsonString, function (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        response($.map(data.list, function (value, key) {
                            return {
                                label: value,
                                value: key
                            };
                        }));
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
                delay: 100
            });

        });
</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
        <hr />
    <input type="text" id="busPoint">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My HTML code

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <hr />       
    <input type="text" id="busPoint">
</div>
```

My Javascript code

```
  <script>

    $(function () {
        var myArray = '[{"OriginId":2609,"OriginName":"14th Mile Stone"},{"OriginId":2007,"OriginName":"Aachara"},{"OriginId":2220,"OriginName":"Aarni"},{"OriginId":2216,"OriginName":"Aasind"},{"OriginId":637,"OriginName":"Aathankarai"},{"OriginId":1292,"OriginName":"Aatthur"},{"OriginId":1144,"OriginName":"Aavanam"},{"OriginId":2909,"OriginName":"Abad (Airport)"},{"OriginId":379,"OriginName":"Abiramam"},{"OriginId":4556,"OriginName":"ABLOLI"},{"OriginId":4554,"OriginName":"ABLOLI KALE HOUSE"},{"OriginId":2346,"OriginName":"Abohar"},{"OriginId":2500,"OriginName":"Abu Road"},{"OriginId":4395,"OriginName":"ACHALPUR"},{"OriginId":1594,"OriginName":"Achanta"},{"OriginId":2769,"OriginName":"Adda Road"}]';

        var jsonString = JSON.parse(myArray);
        $('#busPoint').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON(jsonString, function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                        return {
                            label: value,
                            value: key
                        };
                    }));
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            delay: 100
        });
    });

</script>
```

I have tried this code , but it is not working. 
I need to extract the originid and name on select . 
Most of the sample contains connection to external json or webservice pull , but my data is on the same page.
If their is any other i can use besides this please let me know

Comment: can you create jsfiddle to debug

Comment: added please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script tag doesn't have any ending tag. Besides, I've test your code locally and find out that, code after this line: `$.getJSON(jsonString, function (data) {` isn't executing. After little google search, i found that $.getJSON is used for getting data from server side, but in your code that's not necessary as you have your data in a local variable.

Your solution might be like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var myArray = '[{"OriginId":2609,"OriginName":"14th Mile Stone"},{"OriginId":2007,"OriginName":"Aachara"},{"OriginId":2220,"OriginName":"Aarni"},{"OriginId":2216,"OriginName":"Aasind"},{"OriginId":637,"OriginName":"Aathankarai"},{"OriginId":1292,"OriginName":"Aatthur"},{"OriginId":1144,"OriginName":"Aavanam"},{"OriginId":2909,"OriginName":"Abad (Airport)"},{"OriginId":379,"OriginName":"Abiramam"},{"OriginId":4556,"OriginName":"ABLOLI"},{"OriginId":4554,"OriginName":"ABLOLI KALE HOUSE"},{"OriginId":2346,"OriginName":"Abohar"},{"OriginId":2500,"OriginName":"Abu Road"},{"OriginId":4395,"OriginName":"ACHALPUR"},{"OriginId":1594,"OriginName":"Achanta"},{"OriginId":2769,"OriginName":"Adda Road"}]';

            var jsonString = JSON.parse(myArray);
            $('#busPoint').autocomplete({
                source: $.map(jsonString, function(item) {
                    return item.OriginName;
                }),
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var selectecItem = jsonString.filter(function(value) {
                        return value.OriginName == ui.item.value;
                    });
                    alert("OriginId: " + selectecItem[0].OriginId + ", OriginName: " + selectecItem[0].OriginName);
                },
                minLength: 2,
                delay: 100
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <hr />
        <input type="text" id="busPoint">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tested it locally. Let me know if that's what you want.

Comment: so is their any way to handle this kind of scenario ?

Comment: This answer is modified, please check and let me know.